# How to put xpages Regex (First Character and last character) cannot be special character

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

currently i only allow can let the field do not allow special character 
by using this regex : ^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$

If i just want dont let user to pass for first and last character, what should i put on regex?

sample like :

**.Apple = fail**

**Appplepie. = fail**

**Apple.Pie = pass**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._]*[a-zA-Z]$
```